# How to remove everything after the last occurence of a character in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `DF` that looks like this (This is a sample):

```
    EQ1                    EQ2                       EQ3
0   Apple.fruit            Oranage.eatable.fruit     NaN
1   Pear.eatable.fruit     Banana.fruit              NaN
2   Orange.fruit           Tomato.eatable            Potato.eatable.vegetable
3   Kiwi.eatable           Pear.fruit                Cabbage.vegetable
<And so on.. It is a large Dataframe>
```

I would like to remove everything **AFTER** the LAST occurrence of the dot `.` in every element of `DF` and save it under a different name,say `df_temp`.
Desired ouput:

```
   EQ1               EQ2                 EQ3
0   Apple            Oranage.eatable     NaN
1   Pear.eatable     Banana              NaN
2   Orange           Tomato              Potato.eatable
3   Kiwi             Pear                Cabbage
<And so on>
```

This is what I tried:
`df_temp=".".join(DF.split(".")[:-1])`. 
Unfortunately this seems to  work only with strings and not Dataframe. Do I have to tweak this line a bit to achieve what I want? Someone please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do:

```
df_temp = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('.').str[:-1].str.join('.'))
```

output:

```
            EQ1              EQ2             EQ3
0         Apple  Oranage.eatable             NaN
1  Pear.eatable           Banana             NaN
2        Orange           Tomato  Potato.eatable
3          Kiwi             Pear         Cabbage
```

see the [string method docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings)

Comment: Not worth a separate answer, but `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.rsplit(".",1).str[0])` should do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use extract.

```
df_temp = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.extract(r'.*\.([^\.]*)', expand=False))

df_new = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.extract(r'(.*)\.[^\.]*', expand=False))
```

`df_temp` looks like:

```
       EQ1      EQ2        EQ3
0    fruit    fruit        NaN
1    fruit    fruit        NaN
2    fruit  eatable  vegetable
3  eatable    fruit  vegetable
```

`df_new` looks like:

```
            EQ1              EQ2             EQ3
0         Apple  Oranage.eatable             NaN
1  Pear.eatable           Banana             NaN
2        Orange           Tomato  Potato.eatable
3          Kiwi             Pear         Cabbage
```